# How to Download DSYM file from iTunes Connect (Xcode archives lost)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, crashlytics, dsym

1. I need the DSYM files to analyse the .crash files.
2. All the archives are deleted from my system
3. itunesconnect not showing option to download the DSYM file

So the mystery is, from where can I get the DSYM ?

Also, I am using Fabric/Crashlytics, so is there any way I can download the DSYM from Fabric?

[image: No option for download DSYM]

Comment: I use Bitrise for CI deployments and so the VM is destroyed along with all archives and dsyms. I need a way to download these from iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 5):

As it stands, if you have Bitcode disabled in your app, the option to download dsyms will not be enabled in iTunesConnect.

Comment: Do you know why it is so?

Comment: When you build without bitcode enabled you get only a machine code and a dSYM compatible with your machine code and dSYM is not inside your ipa.  When you build with bitcode enabled, you get a bitcode and a machine code in your ipa. When App Store optimizes your ipa, it recompile it using bitcode and generates a new dSYM from this process. So if you don’t include the bitcode then App Store won’t recompile your ipa, optimize and generate a new dSYM.